# Auth::attempt return False

Tags: laravel-8

My problem with `Auth::attempt` return False
I'm moving from `codeignter` to `laravel 8`
I start with new `laravel` project and connected with my `DB`
Ihis is my controller (change password to to save hash password in `DB`)

```
public function loginCheck(Request $request)
    {

        dd(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password]));  // return false


        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password])) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }

      return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.']);
}

public function changePasswordAction(Request $request){
        $user=User::where('u_username',$request->username)->orWhere('email',$request->email)->first();
        // dd($user);

        //new pass
        $user->password = Hash::make('123456');
        $user->save();

}
```

this my user model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'u_id';
    public $timestamps = true;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'u_fullname',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        // 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }

}
```

Email filed in `DB`:
email   varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci

Password filed in `DB`:
password varchar(255)   utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have find solution i just remove this funcation from user model

```
 public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }
```

its was made a duplication in Hash code